# Abuse report for an email message from amazonses.com

Tags: email, spam, gmail, amazon-ses

I'm an AWS SES user.

I'm getting emails from `complaints@email-abuse.amazonses.com`
with this message:

> This is an email abuse report for an email message from amazonses.com

Based on this [Why do I receive messages from complaints@email-abuse.amazonses.com?](https://support.picnet.net/hc/en-us/articles/114094066791-Why-do-I-receive-messages-from-complaints-email-abuse-amazonses-com-)

I know that

> When you receive such an email, you should verify that the complaining recipient is not included in your future email sends.  This will ensure that you have happy email recipients and fall under the good graces of Amazon SES.

Now, my question - what can I do to reverse this action? What if customer did it by mistake, or he did not think it through.

My business is selling coupons online, sometimes with subscription.
Now what if someone make my email as a spam? I need to notify this person that his email address will never be used for future emails and I need to offer people an option to resubscribe to our service if they did it by mistake.

1) What can I recommend them todo? What is the procedure for a customer to unmark my email address as SPAM?

2) How can I deliver this message if I'm not allowed to email?

3) Does it mean that only one email address of mine was blacklisted or whole domain?

Thanks

Comment: 1, 2 & 3: it depends. There's no one-size-fits-all solution everyone is using, making it impossible to answer any of your questions.